# How to conclude, regression results can't be improved anymore?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to forecast sector's 1 month forward return using macroeconomic factors(170 factors). I tried a few things:

**For Factor Selection**
a)Running regression with one indep and dep and then using indep whose p-values are less than 0.05
b) Running step wise regression for factor selection
Finally running elastic net with best factors (chosen using above method)
**My observation:**
Results (r2) for test set vary way too much on how data is split (don't know why) and even in best of splits r2 is very less (as per my client) in range of 0.12-0.20. How can I either improve this result, or conclude it can't be improved with linear regression.
I have attached couple of diagnostic plots for indep which have lowest p-values

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may get better response if you ask this question on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for input

Comment: [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be even better